# JDK 7 Windows 7 Automatic installation

Tags: windows-7, uninstallation, java-7

Last week, I just found along with Windows update got JDK 7 installed. I uninstalled it as I don't need it. But after restarting machine, JDK 7 got installed again.

Is there anyway to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is list of actions for Windows XP.

Control Panel-> Java. Go to the tab Update and uncheck "check for updates automatically". Afterwards, go to Control Panel->Add or remove programs and uninstall JDK 7 from there.

Comment: How to do it in Windows 7? I could see update/uninstall only.

Comment: Look here http://help.aol.com/help/microsites/microsite.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=21041 and here http://www.sevenforums.com/software/152646-java-auto-updater-driving-me-crazy.html